# PC has stopped booting on a schedule

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, scheduled-tasks

My PC has been set to boot at 4:30 am for a year, and has worked flawlessly.  It's set in the BIOS (Gigabyte X299 UD4 Motherboard).

A few days ago I was looking through the BIOS and saw that Fast Boot was disabled.  I enabled it, and the machine stopped booting in the mornings.  Research taught me that this feature will disable the ability for the machine to boot up on schedule.  So I turned it back off again.  Now the PC won't boot on a schedule anymore at all even though it's still enabled to do so and Fast Boot is turned off.

How do I get it to boot on a schedule again?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the old schedule and putting it back, and/or changing the time, e.g. to 4:29 AM?

Comment: Yep sure did... in fact I chose exactly 4:29am lol.  No change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going on.  Turns out there are two different "Fast Boots".  One is in the BIOS, one is in Windows.  Somehow, the one in Windows got enabled, maybe as part of enabling it in the BIOS?  I'm not sure... but for sure turning OFF the BIOS Fast Boot did not turn it off in Windows, therefore apparently the machine was not actually shutting down fully.  Not that I've disabled Windows Fast Boot (Advance Power Settings), it is once again starting up on schedule.

[This is the thread I found](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/26529-bios-startup-not-happening.html) that gave me the solution.